# Computer USB Port Cover

Tags: usb, cleaning, maintenance

I have recently brought a computer with a unique design (which I thought was cool!). The USB port is facing upwards, meaning my USB thumb drive will be placed vertically, as in, in an upright position.

Now, when I had it for a initial few days, I thought it was really cool, however, now a lot of dust gets into the port which then requires clean up.

Is there anything similar to a USB thumb drive which I can generally keep plugged in to the port so that it prevents dust getting collected in it?

Comment: consider leaving a spare USB key plugged into the port until you can get a good cover for it.

Comment: Quack, why didn't you make your comment an answer?

Comment: cause it's not an answer?  it's a workaround.  Kevin Boyd's answer is spot-on, no need to distract from it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

**USB Protective Cover**..
Found on Amazon you could find more details [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AA2OWM).

Comment: What a nifty idea.

Comment: Brilliant idea! Thanks a lot Kevin. I will place an order right away!

Answer (score 0):

How about black duct tape? It's not fancy but you probably already have some lying around.

Seriously though I doubt dust would be a problem with USB ports as the connectors scrape aganist the exposed connector and would probably push all the dust to the bottom of the port.